# How to get file names from the directory, not the entire path

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

I am using the below method to get the file names. But it returns the entire path and I don't want to get the entire path. I want only file names, not the entire path.

How can I get that only file names not the entire path

`path= c:\docs\doc\backup-23444444.zip`

```
string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(targetdirectory,"backup-*.zip");
foreach (string filename in filenames)
{ }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could use the [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method to extract only the filename without a path:

```
string filenameWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(filename);
```

Comment: I have lot of files with same type how can i get list of files that filenames only contains that file name

Answer (score 12):

[`System.IO.Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) is your friend here:

```
var filenames = from fullFilename
                in Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetdirectory,"backup-*.zip")
                select Path.GetFileName(fullFilename);

foreach (string filename in filenames)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what i have to put  in this place fullFilename  do i have to give

Answer (score 3):

Try `GetFileName()` method:

```
Path.GetFileName(filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this, it will give you all file's name without Extension

    List<string> lstAllFileName = (from itemFile in dir.GetFiles()
                                               select Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(itemFile.FullName)).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq is good

Directory.GetFiles( dir ).Select( f => Path.GetFileName( f ) ).ToArray();