# How to write mass amount of <li><img> tags with specific names? Files named in folder/server

Tags: html, image, file, tags, url-rewriting

I have bunch of image files at one server directory

```
servername/images/picture-name.jpg 
servername/images/differentname.jpg  
servername/images/hundredmore.jpg
```

I want to make them into a bunch of html tags in one go.

```
<li><img src="http://domain.com/images/picturename.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="http://domain.com/images/differentname.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="http://domain.com/images/hundredmore.jpg"/></li>
```

I also have the images in a folder on my hdd. Any idea how to take file-names and build these lists? For reference of my skill level, I only know html/css/ and bit of javascript. I guess you got to grab the file-names somehow and make a program that writes `"<li><img...."` before and `"/></li>` after the grabbed name.

Comment: You need a server-side language (PHP, JSP, ASP) to do this easily.

Comment: If you already know some JavaScript and don't have an existing server-side platform, check out Node.js. http://nodejs.org/ It might be ideal for you as you can then write JS for both your server-side and client-side code and not need to learn another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you name your files 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc, then it's easy. in php it would look like this (edited to reflect names not numbers):

```
$dir = "path to image folder";
$dh = opendir($dir);

$link = '"http://domain.com/images/';

while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
{
   echo '<li><img src='.$link.$file.'" /></li>';

}

closedir($dh);
```

javascript would look very similar to this. if you want to keep descriptive file names, then you either need to do it manually, or add code to read the file names from the directory

Comment: Thanks, but yes I actually need to keep the descriptive file names, so anyone else go any more guesses?

Comment: this is for c#, but if you can find a method that works like this, you can create an associative array with a count-like variable as the key, and the file names as values and use the same method as above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737461/how-to-get-only-file-names-from-the-directory-not-the-entire-path

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Worked well. For anyone else doing the same thing you can 1-click clean up the html later with http://infohound.net/tidy - (the php generates all tags on 1 line). Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I totally forgot about the ALT attribute. And the "Alt=" should be without dashes, so it's going to be more even complicated.. I could mass-rename the dashes(-) to a spaces with a program I have, but it probably would be no good as then I still need the dashes for the url.. Let me know if you know how to add the alt attribute while making these tags..

Comment: it SHOULD be something like '<li><img alt="'.$file.'" src="'.$link.$file.'" /></li>'; but i'm not getting alt text to show up on mouseover on my end

Comment: Hey, I got it working. The alt tags come with dashes(-) tho and a .jpg file extension.

Comment: Used the following: echo  '<li><img alt="'.$file.'" src='.$link.$file.'" /></li>';